# copying multi-level Python dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, copy

I have below Python dictionary as `source`

```
d1 = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': [{'d': 3, 'e': 4, 'un': 'wanted1', 'dont': 'needthis1'},
        {'d': 5, 'e': 6, 'un': 'wanted2', 'dont': 'needthis2'}]
  'xyz': 'abc',
  'zxy': 'cab',
  'wva': 'xyw'
}
```

And I want to copy the values of some specific keys to a different dict to form below `target` dictionary

```
d2 = {
  'some_attr_1': 1,  
  'some_attr_x': 2,
  'attr_some_z': [{'attr_x': 3, 'attrib': 4},
                  {'attr_x': 5, 'attrib': 6}]
}
```

Note:

- I am not interested in all the attributes from `source` 
  for ex: I don't need keys `xyz`, `zxy`, etc
- Basically, Want values for some keys in `source` to be mapped 
  to different keys in `target` dictionary.

My current approach is as below to have mapping between `source` and `target` dictionary keys.

```
attr_map1 = {
   'some_attr_1': 'a',
   'some_attr_x': 'b'
}

attr_map2 = {
  'attr_x': 'd',
  'attrib': 'e',
}

d2 = dict()
for k, v in attr_map1.items():
   d2[k] = d1[v]

l1 = list()
for d_elem in d1['c']:
   temp_dict = dict()
   for k, v in attr_map2.items():
       temp_dict[k] = d_elem[v]
   l1.append(temp_dict)
d2['attr_some_z'] = l1
```

Is there any alternate, better and speedy approach to achieve this?

I am looking for a solution in Python 2.7.

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion:

```
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [{'d': 3, 'e': 4}, {'d': 5, 'e': 6}]}
def build(d):
  return {f't_{a}':b if not isinstance(b, (dict, list)) else 
           list(map(build, b)) if isinstance(b, list) else build(b) for a, b in d.items()}

print(build(d1))
```

Output:

```
{
't_a': 1, 
 't_b': 2, 
 't_c': [
    {'t_d': 3, 't_e': 4}, 
    {'t_d': 5, 't_e': 6}
   ]
}
```

Edit: to run this solution in Python2, replace the `f-string` with simple concatenation:

```
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [{'d': 3, 'e': 4}, {'d': 5, 'e': 6}]}
def build(d):
   return {'t_'+a:b if not isinstance(b, (dict, list)) else 
       list(map(build, b)) if isinstance(b, list) else build(b) for a, b in d.items()}
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution in Python2

Comment: OK. This works if the keys are in the form like `t_a - a, t_b - b`. I gave this as example. But keys in my original problems are entirely different. like `hwPhyAddress - hardware-physical-address`.

Comment: @SubhakarKS What is your desired output from `hwPhyAddress - hardware-physical-address`?